# Showing that if $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is a measurable real valued function on $(S, \mathcal{S})$, then so is $\lambda f$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have somehow confused myself with this fairly straightforward proof. We need to show that $\lambda f$ is a measurable function on $(S, \mathcal{S})$, i.e. that for any $c \in \mathbb{R}: \{s \in S: f(s) \leq c\} \subset S$. If $\lambda \neq 0$, then the claim follows immediately from the measurability of $f$, namely as $c/\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ it follows that $\{s \in S: f(s) \leq c/\lambda \} = \{s \in S: \lambda f(s) \leq c \}$

But then, if $\lambda = 0, \lambda f = 0$ and I am not sure how to convince myself that $\lambda f$ is measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda=0$, then your function $\lambda f=0$ is identically $0$. The inverse image of any measurable set containing $0$ is $S$ and of any set not containing $0$ is the empty set. Both of these are measurable.

Comment: Why is the inverse image of any measurable set containing 0 the set $S$?

Comment: Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set containing $0$. Then, $\{s\in S: \lambda f(s) =0 \} \subseteq \{s\in S: \lambda f(s)\in A \}$. But $\{s\in S: \lambda f(s) =0 \}=S$ because $\lambda f$ is $0$ for all $s \in S$. So  $S \subseteq \{s\in S: \lambda f(s)\in A \} \subseteq S $.

Answer (score 1):

$f:{S}\to \Bbb{R}$ measurable function.

$g:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) =\lambda x$ , $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$ , is continuous.

Hence, $g\circ  f=\lambda f$ is measurable.